# XACT_ABORT and Atomicity of transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've just heard the theory that the instruction `SET XACT_ABORT OFF` breaks Atomicity of transaction SQL Server. Looking at the example from this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms188792.aspx) I thought that SQL Server closes the explicit transaction and start new, implicit one. So the statement isn't atomic, but transaction is!

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1);  
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (2); -- Foreign key error.  
INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (3);  
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Who is right?

Comment: Sometimes an error causes a transaction to be aborted, and sometimes it doesn't and it only aborts the statement. `ROLLBACK` always rolls back, and `COMMIT` always commits, so in that sense atomicity is guaranteed, but this may still cause surprises as to exactly *what* will be committed. If you want to know exactly when "sometimes" is, there's [this table](http://sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part2.html#classification) -- it depends on `XACT_ABORT`, whether or not you're in a `TRY .. CATCH`, and the statement itself -- not easily summarized. Bottom line: `XACT_ABORT ON` is a really good idea.

Comment: That said, it's definitely not the case that SQL Server closes the transaction and starts a new one; in your example, the transaction commits successfully, but statement 2 aborts independently and simply has no effect. Yes, this is confusing and troublesome if you're counting on all statements happening or none of them, and foreign key violations are probably the most common way to discover this.